# How do I calculate all pairs of vector differences in numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-einsum

I know I can do `np.subtract.outer(x, x)`.  If `x` has shape `(n,)`, then I end up with an array with shape `(n, n)`.  However, I have an `x` with shape `(n, 3)`.  I want to output something with shape `(n, n, 3)`.  How do I do this?  Maybe `np.einsum`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after extending the dimensions with [`None`/`np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to form a 3D array version of `x` and subtracting the original 2D array version from it, like so -

```
x[:, np.newaxis, :] - x
```

Sample run -

```
In [6]: x
Out[6]: 
array([[6, 5, 3],
       [4, 3, 5],
       [0, 6, 7],
       [8, 4, 1]])

In [7]: x[:,None,:] - x
Out[7]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 2,  2, -2],
        [ 6, -1, -4],
        [-2,  1,  2]],

       [[-2, -2,  2],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 4, -3, -2],
        [-4, -1,  4]],

       [[-6,  1,  4],
        [-4,  3,  2],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [-8,  2,  6]],

       [[ 2, -1, -2],
        [ 4,  1, -4],
        [ 8, -2, -6],
        [ 0,  0,  0]]])
```

Comment: Well, this was a lot simpler than I anticipated :)